# winsock library is not identified by codelite IDE

Tags: windows, sockets, codelite

I am using codelite IDE on windows,
in that when I was trying to compile socket program,

it shows:
warning: ignoring #pragma comment  [-Wunknown-pragmas]

for include "WinSock2.h"
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

Answer (score 0):

First, some clarifications: codelite is not a compiler but an IDE
It uses toolchains (GNU, VC etc)

So when you are saying that "winsock library is not identified by codelite IDE" you actually means: the compiler warns about #pragma

Since you do not provide additional information here (such as the build log, the compiler you are using, codelite version etc) I will take a guess here and would say that you are mixingg the GNU toolchain with VC headers - try to use the WinAPI that comes with MinGW instead.

Looking at the WinSock2.h that comes with GCC for Windows I see only this pragma:

```
#pragma GCC system_header
```

Also, .lib libraries are meant to be used by VC but not by GCC

Eran

Comment: Thank you Eran and yes...that problem solved, I added -lws2_32 in linker and it works.